# Loading an Optional Component with ASDF

Tags: common-lisp, asdf

How do you tell ASDF to process a component file only if it exists (so it doesn't generate an error if it doesn't exist yet).

```
(asdf:defsystem "my-system"
  :components ((:file "utilities")
               (:file "temp-file" :depends-on ("utilities"))))
```

My workaround is using a reader macro #. on `(probe-file "temp-file")` but can't get that to work.

Comment: [This looks somewhat promising](https://github.com/fare/asdf/blob/master/doc/best_practices.md#conditional_code). No idea whether it does what you want, so not putting it as answer. Why do you want to do this, anyway?

Comment: Yeah, this looks like you're generating source files, which I personally regard as an antipattern.  What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: It's strictly a development convenience to sometimes bypass compiling & loading a problem specification file along with the system. I guess I could create a dummy specification, but thought it would be easier to just check if a specification file exists.

Comment: Why not `#|...code...|#` comment syntax around the file contents if you are aiming to block out a file? ASDF would succeed upon loading an "empty" (according to the lisp reader) file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you really are trying to do is have ASDF merely warn you instead of bringing up the debugger during compilation errors. Change `*compile-file-warnings-behaviour*` and `*compile-file-failure-behaviour*`, and read [the section on error handling](https://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/asdf.html#Error-handling) in the manual.

The rest of this answer is how to check for a whole system. You could package the maybe-to-load files into their own systems and do it this way below.

From the [ASDF Manual section 6.3.8](https://www.common-lisp.net/project/asdf/asdf.html#Weakly-depends-on).

> 6.3.8 Weakly depends on
>
> We do NOT recommend you use this feature.

So you could just use it anyway. Like this:

```lisp
(defpackage :foo-system
  (:use :cl :asdf))
(in-package :foo-system)
(defsystem foo
  :description "The main package that maybe loads bar if it exists."
  :weakly-depends-on (:bar)
  :components ((:file "foo")))
```

Simple right?

Here is what they recommend:

> If you are tempted to write a system foo that weakly-depends-on a
>   system bar, we recommend that you should instead write system foo in a
>   parametric way, and offer some special variable and/or some hook to
>   specialize its behaviour; then you should write a system foo+bar that
>   does the hooking of things together.

I've never seen one of these in the wild, probably because it is a horrible confusing mess to do it that way.

```lisp
(defpackage :bar-system
  (:use :cl :asdf))
(in-package :bar-system)
(defsystem bar
  :description "The package that maybe exists and is needed by foo."
  :components ((:file "bar")))

(defpackage :foo+bar-system
  (:use :cl :asdf))
(in-package :foo+bar-system)
(defsystem foo+bar
  :version      "0.1.0"
  :description  "Hook together foo and bar."
  :author       "Spenser Truex <web@spensertruex.com>"
  :serial       t
  :components ((:file "foo+bar")))

(defpackage :foo-system
  (:use :cl :asdf))
(in-package :foo-system)
(defsystem foo
  :description "The main package that maybe loads bar if it exists."
  :depends-on (:foo+bar)
  :components ((:file "foo")))
```